# 100% height of element not working

Tags: html, css

I want to make the .contents and .root height 100%
I did every try but did not achieved the expectation.

here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dashboard | The Design In - The Pure CMS</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-top"><img src="images/logo.png" width="171" height="40" alt="ThePureCMS">

</div>

<div class="sidebar">aaa</div>
<div class="root">
 <div class="contents">

  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <!-- BODY END -->
 </div>
<footer>
  <div>copyrights 2013 | The Design In | www.thedesignin.com</div>
 </footer>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
body, hrml {
background-color: #efefef;
width: 100% !important;
min-height: 100% !important;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.root {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100% !important;
min-height: 500px !important;
float: left;
}
.navbar-top {
background-image: url(../images/nav_bg.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: left top;
min-height:40px !important;
margin:0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
}
.sidebar, .contents{
height: auto;
min-height:100%;
padding-top:40px;
}
.sidebar{
width:171px;
float:left;
background-color:#2e3b81;
position:fixed;
}
.contents {
margin-left: 171px;
display: block;
background-color: #fafafa;
padding:16px;
padding-top:56px;
padding-bottom:71px;
}

footer {
width:100%;
margin-left:0;
position:relative;
padding:0;
bottom:0;
color:#d5d5d5;
background-color:transparent;
}
footer div {
margin-right:16px;
margin-left:187px;
margin-top:-55px;
margin-bottom:16px;
padding-top:12px;
padding-bottom:11px;
color:#2e3b81;
background:url(../images/footer_bg.png) repeat-x left top;
font-size:11px;
}
```

Please help me to make the container height 100%.
I dont want to use the javascript or jquery.

Long time ago I did achieved the height 100%, but dont know am I doing mistake this time....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<html><body>` to `<html height="100%"><body height="100%">`

I have just set the background color of root to red color.Scroll down and see that it is of the same height as of the window:

http://jsfiddle.net/wJ2Tx/2/

Fiddle for what you asked in the comment:

http://jsfiddle.net/7VmQW/1/

After removing padding:

http://jsfiddle.net/7VmQW/8/

Comment: html and body are working good. only the .root is not excepting the height

Comment: Ok, I am waiting for a fiddle. Please try

Comment: here is the my fiddle. gray div ( .contents ) need to be 100% in height to fill the all area

Comment: Sorry, but I want .contents and .root class to be 100%

Comment: I saw the fiddle, it covers the area. But if I place some contents in .contens div, it brooked. and the changes you made ?

Comment: Thanks Zword, Its working now. Thanking you again for you time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to give your body tag some sort of tangible height for the children to be 100%.

Comment: Yes -- instead of `min-height` in your `body, html` directive, try `height:100%`.

Comment: Did not get you. can you give me some more explanation please

Comment: Try height:300px; as an example.

Comment: I've had it working with %age on min-height. http://blog.paulwilliams.biz/2013/11/test.html as an example (you'll have to collapse the November archive to get the effect.)

Comment: I have noticed that the body height working correctly 100%. I debug it by background color. Also tried by giving 500px height to body , html and .root in firebug: .root is floated and no height on it

Comment: here is the my fiddle. gray div ( .contents ) need to be 100% in height to fill the all area. http://jsfiddle.net/7VmQW/

Answer (score 0):

in your example, you have `body, hrml {`.  You might want to make that `html`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I have tried this. Not working :(